# Custom Json Converter with no default Constructor and .NET Native

Tags: .net, json.net, win-universal-app, .net-native

I'm writing app on Universal Windows Platform (Win10). And had a problem using a custom Json Converter when running on release mode which meaning compile through .NET Native. Here's my converter's code

```
public class NestedObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private string childNodeName;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }

        var rootObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var childToken = rootObject[childNodeName];
        return ServiceModelJsonConvert.DeserializeObject(childToken, objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(childNodeName);
        writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public NestedObjectJsonConverter(string childNodeName)
    {
        this.childNodeName = childNodeName;
    }
}
```

when trigger this converter on release mode. it gets "creation error" exception but it works fine under debug mode.

I've log my exception meesage

> HResult : -2146233088 TypeName : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException,
>   Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed Message :
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Error creating
>   'NestedObjectJsonConverter'. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.<>c.b__18_1(Object
>   param)    at
>   System.Func.Invoke(Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder
>   arg)    at SharedLibrary!+0x3a908c    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x3b1492    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d376a    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Func.Invoke(Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder
>   arg)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetJsonConverter(Object
>   attributeProvider)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.SetPropertySettingsFromAttributes(Json.Serialization.JsonProperty
>   property, Object attributeProvider, String name, Type declaringType,
>   Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization, Boolean&
>   allowNonPublicAccess)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperty(Reflection.MemberInfo
>   member, Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties(Type
>   type, Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type
>   objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type
>   objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type
>   type)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe(Type
>   type)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Json.JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Json.JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Json.JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)

It seems finding parameterized constructor is the root cause of this issue in .NET Native. But this is an but of .NET Native or JSON.NET ?

Comment: I would suggest setting your project to DEBUG mode but with .NET Native enabled (there's a checkbox for this in your project properties). This should raise exceptions with some helpful messages. Updating to VS Update 1 may also be beneficial.

Comment: @MattWhilden : OK~ Thanks~ I'll try that option

Comment: @WiredPrairie : when de-serialize and trigger this converter. It will get "creation error" exception thrown from JSON.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a .net Native bug. And it was fixed in current release